# How to give different tags to buttons in different TableView cells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app where users writes entries to different topics then can give up and down points to the entries. I used in my tableViewController the function:

> func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

and I added these two lines at the end of this function:

```
cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.minusButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

So this should give every button in the tableView a tag so that its the same as indexpath.row of that cell, am I wrong? Because when I then try to call the buttons, all of their tags are same and equals to 0. How can I give them different tags? Is there no way to do so in this way?

This is what the code is when I want to call the button:

```
@IBAction func plus(sender: AnyObject) {

    print(self.tag)

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("topics/"+topicClicked+"/"+entriesArrayTwo[self.tag])

    var value = Int()
    var date = String()
    var user = String()
    var votedDown = [""]
    var votedUp = [""]

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        value = dict["point"] as! Int
        date = String(dict["date"]!)
        user = String(dict["user"]!)
        votedUp = dict["votedUp"] as! NSArray as! [String]
        votedDown = dict["votedDown"] as! NSArray as! [String]

        var tempBool = false
        var temp = -1

        for uid in votedDown {
            temp = temp + 1

            if uid == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                votedDown.removeAtIndex(temp)
                tempBool = true
            }
        }

        if tempBool == false {
            votedUp.append((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)
        }

        ref.setValue(["point": value+1, "date": date, "user": user, "votedDown": votedDown, "votedUp": votedUp])

        self.point.text = String(value+1)
    })

    if minusButton.hidden == true {
        minusButton.hidden = false
    } else {
        plusButton.hidden = true
    }
}
```

My tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell function is below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "entryCell", for: indexPath) as! HubEntryTableViewCell

    if self.resultSearchController.isActive {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("topics/"+topicClicked+"/"+filteredTableData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            cell.point.text = String(describing: value!["point"]!)

            let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/"+String(describing: value!["user"]!))

            postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { snapshotTwo in

                let valueTwo = snapshotTwo.value as? NSDictionary

                cell.subInfo.text = String(describing: valueTwo!["name"]!)+" "+String(describing: valueTwo!["surname"]!)+" - "+String(describing: value!["date"]!)

            })


            })

        cell.entry.text = self.filteredTableData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    } else {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("topics/"+topicClicked+"/"+entriesArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            cell.point.text = String(describing: value!["point"]!)

            let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/"+String(describing: value!["user"]!))

            postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { snapshotTwo in

                let valueTwo = snapshotTwo.value as? NSDictionary

            cell.subInfo.text = String(describing: valueTwo!["name"]!)+" "+String(describing: valueTwo!["surname"]!)+" - "+String(describing: value!["date"]!)

            })

            let votedUpRef = ref.child("votedUp")

            votedUpRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { upSnapshot in

                var tempDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let tempArray = tempDict["votedUp"] as! [String]

                for uid in tempArray {

                    if String(uid) == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

                        cell.plusButton.isHidden = true

                    }

                }

            })

            let votedDownRef = ref.child("votedDown")

            votedUpRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { upSnapshot in

                var tempDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let tempArray = tempDict["votedDown"] as! [String]

                for uid in tempArray {

                    if String(uid) == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

                        cell.minusButton.isHidden = true

                    }

                }

            })

        })

        cell.entry.text = self.entriesArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    }

    cell.plusButton.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    cell.minusButton.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

    // NEW METHOD TO GET THE BUTTON

    let check1: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton)
    let check2: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton)
    check1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HubEntriesTableViewController.CloseMethod(_:event:)), for: .touchDown)
    check2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HubEntriesTableViewController.CloseMethod1(_:event:)), for: .touchDown)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Share our paste your entire code with what you are doing in button click

Comment: I'm referring to a database, with child coming from the tag of the pressed button. Something like this:
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referance().child("self.tag"), but tag is always 0 in my case

Comment: set cell.buttonPlus.Tag = indexpath.row+UniqueNumber
set cell.buttonMinus.Tag = indexpath.row+UniqueNumber(different)

And you can get it easily.

Comment: @DevThakur can you be more specific? what is uniqueNumber and buttonPlusTag? are they different variables?

Comment: Like For minus button Unique number may be (1000) and for plus i will use (5000) now i can set tag like cell.plusbutton.tag = indexpath.row+(5000) 
and when i will get it i can decrease button.tag by uniqueNumber 
Example : tag will be 50001 (for indexpath.row ==1) 
newTag = btnTag-(UniqueNumber)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps finally found an issue. When I reproduced the problem in my project, I realised that **downcasting to** `UIButton` was missing.

So within `HubEntryTableViewCell` subclass update the method like this:

```
@IBAction func plus(sender: AnyObject) {

    // self.tag, if called from UITableViewCell subclass, is rather cell's tag, not button's tag

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    print("button.tag = \(button.tag)")
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have only one section

Comment: It properly show the indexpath.rows as 0,1,2 and so on. There is no problem with that. Also when I 'print(cell.plusButton.tag)' it gives properly 0,1,2... @pedrouan

Answer (score 0):

**If you have perform action on button click in tableview then try this code you don't worry about tag ..**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Eventcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   let check1: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UIButton)
   let check2: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIButton)   
    check1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EventListController.CloseMethod(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    check2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EventListController.CloseMethod1(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    return cell
 }
  @IBAction func CloseMethod(sender: UIButton, event: AnyObject) {
        let touches = event.allTouches()!
        let touch = touches.first!
        let currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInView(self.Eventlisttable)
        let indexPath = self.Eventlisttable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!
        print("\(Int(indexPath.row))")

  }
  @IBAction func CloseMethod1(sender: UIButton, event: AnyObject) {
        let touches = event.allTouches()!
        let touch = touches.first!
        let currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInView(self.Eventlisttable)
        let indexPath = self.Eventlisttable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!
        print("\(Int(indexPath.row))")
 }
```

**If my answer help you then give vote. thank you..**

Comment: All I want to do is increment and decrement the "point" value of entry from database, when the appropriate button is clicked. I mean when + button is pressed I want to increment by 1, and when minus is clicked the other way.

Comment: then you can do this your operation in CloseMethod for that particular cell. In my case i have to perform some action in tableview for particular cell data ... my table is Eventlisttable .

Comment: What are closeMethod and closeMethod1? are they for different buttons? And also cell.viewWithTag(11) and (12), what are those?

Comment: yes both are different button in tableview and that button i access from tag .

Comment: Can you look at the code I edited my original post. Should I do that code in CloseMethod func? If I use your method?

Comment: yes this all code you have to put in closemethod. and this method call for only one cell so your particular one cell data update...

Comment: In short your plus method code you have to put in my CloseMethod . got it ?

Comment: what is Eventlisttable? It gives error has no member. And about selectors, it gives an error in there in EventListController

Comment: Eventlisttable is my table replace with your tablename  and EventlistController is my controller replace it with your controllername.

Comment: Okay, so these IBActions should be in my TableViewController or in my tableViewCell.swift file?

Comment: IBAction is only buttonaction that perform some task like .

Comment: It gives fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when I try to run code in the code section:
let check1: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton)

Comment: Show me your this tableview method...  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }

Comment: I added my func to original question. It's in swift3 by the way.